# share common file within multiple channels within teams->general->Files

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm new in teams. I'm a lab manager for different IT team projects. The bigwigs tell us what PDF forms to have the users fill out, but they change on short notice.
Each TEAM->General->Files tab seems to have to have the file uploaded (not good).

I would like to have a single base file and something similar to multiple linux symlinks.

Ideally, the base file is on a shared drive and be accessed within multiple team channels. It can't be in my one drive but in a common area so other admins can update it.

Change the base file and it appears in each TEAM->General->Files tab.

An alternative is to put the file in one team's General->Files tab and have it available in other team's General->Files tab

Is this possible?

PS.This just gives the link and shares with individuals. I need it to be a "file". https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-a-file-to-multiple-channels-in-microsoft-teams-7bd003ce-87e2-4b4e-9f30-b27ef5ea471f